# Cufflinks(Plotly) can't plot date time but numbers on the x-axis for the heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, plotly

I tried to plot a heatmap using Cufflinks API and i changed my pandas dataframe's index to datetime 
[image]

but the x-axis shows scientific numbers rather than dates: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to specify the x-axis tick values explicitly from your pandas index.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go    
import cufflinks as cf
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'C2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'C3': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'C4': [3, 4, 5, 6]},
             index=pd.to_datetime(['2016-11', '2016-12', '2017-01', '2017-02']))

# set the tick values to the index labels directly
layout = go.Layout(xaxis = go.XAxis(
    ticks=df.index.tolist(), 
    showticklabels=True,
    linewidth=1,
    tickvals=df.index.tolist()
))

cf.go_offline()
df.iplot(kind='heatmap', fill=True, colorscale='spectral', filename='cufflinks/test', layout=layout)
```

This produces the plot

[image: pandas cufflinks heatmap example plot]

I arrived here attempting to resolve a similar issue to yours. This post is a little late, but perhaps this will also help future readers.